# APLX: Order a mixed data matrix by second column

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, apl

I'm working in APLX, and I need to order a two column matrix (it will always be two columns) by the second column.  This issue being, the first column contains rows of 7 alphanumeric character sets.  The second column, however, contains a weight or "score" for each row of alphanumeric code.  For example...

```
4ST7SM4     34
XXW1X2X 340000
599E5EE   1516
```

Should be ordered by the numbers on the right so it looks like...

```
XXW1X2X 340000
599E5EE   1516
4ST7SM4     34
```

So always in descending order.  I've played around with the rank down function, but I get a value error, as expected, because the first column is alphanumeric.  I played around with swapping the columns and swapping them back, but it still doesn't work, meaning that it throws the same error.  I could separate them, and rank down the numbers, but I need the alphanumeric plates to reorder with it.  I'm not sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must grade the single, second column, then reorder the entire matrix. Note index origin is zero, if you use 1, replace 1 in bracket indexing with a 2:

```
      m←3 2⍴'4ST7SM4' 34  'XXW1X2X' 34000 '599E5EE' 1516
      m
 4ST7SM4     34
 XXW1X2X  34000
 599E5EE   1516
      ⍒m[;1]
1 2 0
      m[1 2 0;]
 XXW1X2X  34000
 599E5EE   1516
 4ST7SM4     34
```

All in one go:

```
      m[⍋m[;1];]
 4ST7SM4     34
 599E5EE   1516
 XXW1X2X  34000
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, there were grade up and grade down.  These were defined on numeric vectors only.

Then grade up and grade down were extended to operate on character and matrix data.  At I. P. Sharp, this happened around 1980.  Quite probably the others (IBM, STSC) did the same around then.

However, at the time, character grade required a left argument, which was the collating sequence.  Often, []AV was good enough, but if you wanted to do sorts involving upper and lower case letters, you may have had to use something like

```
'aAbBcCdD...zZ0123456789 ' gradeUp mat
```

This might be the reason for the value error in APLX.  Their character grade implementation may need a left argument.  Assuming the second column of your example matrix is character, try your example again with []AV, i.e.

```
m[ []av gradeUp disclose m[;2] ; ]
```